# How to apply an Aria label to a sub-element of a PrimeNG component?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, wai-aria, primeng-dropdowns

## Initial scenario:

- PrimeNG 9.1.0
- Angular 9.1.9

The accessibility test of Google's Lighthouse notes the missing Aria label for the chevron element of the PrimeNG [dropdown component](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown) ("Buttons do not have an accessible name").

My usage in the HTML file:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
```

DOM section generated by PrimeNG accordingly:

```
<div class="ng-tns-c5-7 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-dropdown-clearable">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input class="ng-tns-c5-7" aria-haspopup="listbox" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label=" " kl_vkbd_parsed="true" aria-expanded="false">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dropdown-label-container">
        <span class="ng-tns-c5-7 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-placeholder ng-star-inserted">Select a City</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-clickable pi pi-chevron-down">
        ::before
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Challenge to be solved:

How can I add an aria label to the chevron sub-element (line 8) of the PrimeNG dropdown component if I don't have access to it myself and therefore cannot add an `aria-label="action description"`?

## Target scenario:

Pass the Lighthouse accessibility test.

Comment: in the documentation, there are some aria label parameters.
Have you tried them? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown


The other choice will be to manipulate the aria labels with typescript, after the `onShow` event emitted

Comment: @StPaulis, I suppose you mean the two parameters `ariaLabelledBy` and `ariaFilterLabel`? I have tested both of them, but unfortunately they do not affect the chevron subelement itself. At the same time, PrimeNG sets the value `role="button"` on the chevron sub-element, which is what triggers the annotations of the Lighthouse test.

Comment: @StPaulis, How do you think the `onShow` event approach could look like in Typescript?

Comment: I am not sure, how exactly the control works, I would try to manipulate the elements when the drop down is open.

I played a little while and I saw that the control is already doing a lot of stuff while opening, I am not sure If it will be an easy task.

You can create a ticket in PrimeNg to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting an error that no accessible name for the input box exists inside of the drop-down list after rendering.
Wrapping the drop-down list with a label html element solved the Andi issue.

```
<label>
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian for your advice. Unfortunately, the Lighthouse error message persists even after its implementation. I suspect that the label is implicitly passing the text to the embedded dropdown element, but not to the chevron sub element, causing the error scenario to persist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around.
You can add aria label in typescript code.

For example,
first define your aria label in labels list.
Then,

```
this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-dropdown-trigger");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
        this.elements[i].ariaLabel = this.labels[i];
    }
```